# como colocar un <figcaption> en una <img> dentro de otra <img>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, frontend

quiero que el texto quede en el centro debajo de la img de mi cara
pero no lo que el texto quede como titulo de la img de mi cara

[image: quiero que el texto quede en el centro debajo de la img de mi cara pero no lo que el texto quede como titulo de la img de mi cara]

HTML

```
<img id="Home" class="img-fluid">
<figure class="figure">
  <img id="foto" class="figure-img img-fluid top-50 start-50 translate-middle rounded-circle" src="img/foto.jpg">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption">safafaweraewfw</figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
#Home {
position: relative;
  background-image: url(img/fondo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 630px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;

 }

 #foto{
  position: absolute;
 }
```

quiero que el texto del `<figcaption>` se muestre como titulo de la `<img>` con id="foto"
pero se muestra como titulo de la `<img>` con id="Home"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si cambias la imagen del fondo por un "div" y lo metes dentro del "figure", el texto te queda dentro. Y con flex-box te alineé la imagen y el texto en el centro.

```
    <div id="Home">
        <figure class="figure d-flex align-items-center justify-content- 
             center">
            <div>
                <img id="foto" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded- 
                    circle"
                    src="cara.jpg">
                <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
            </div>
        </figure>
 </div>
```

Y el CSS

```
#Home {
position: relative;
  background-image: url(foto.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
 }
figure{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
 #foto{
     height: 100px;
 }
```

Te saque la posicion absoluta de la imagen porque con flex-box es mejor en mi opinión, si copias esto debería funcionarte
(sino, cambia el  por un  o algo asi, a mi me funciona)

Comment: Muchas gracias Tiziano anda perfecto. Algunos de estos dias tengo que revisar mejor la documentación de Bootstrap en las parte de posiciones. Para entenderlo mejor, muchas gracias genio y voy a seguir aprendiendo suerteeeeeeeee :)

Comment: De nada capo! pone la pregunta como respondida, así no responde nadie más